# Angular JS: 2 applications on the same page, only 1 should affect browser's location

Tags: routes, angularjs

I'm looking for a solution to host 2 Angular JS applications on a single page. The extra requirement is, only 1 of these applications should depend on/affect real URL. Here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app1 = angular.module("app1", [], function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                    .when("/1", { template: "<h1>app 1 page 1</h1>" })
                    .when("/2", { template: "<h1>app 1 page 2</h1>" })
                    .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/1" });
        });

        var app2 = angular.module("app2", [], function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                    .when("/1", { template: "<h1>app 2 page 1</h1>" })
                    .when("/2", { template: "<h1>app 2 page 2</h1>" })
                    .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/1" });
        });

        $(function() {
            angular.bootstrap($(".app1")[0], ["app1"]);
            angular.bootstrap($(".app2")[0], ["app2"]);
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="app1">
        <h1>App 1</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/1">Go 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/2">Go 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>

    <div class="app2">
        <h1>App 2</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#/1">Go 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#/2">Go 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What I want to do is:

**When user navigates to `#/1` manually, the result is:**

```
app 1 page 1
app 2 page 1
```

**When user navigates to `#/2` manually, the result is:**

```
app 1 page 2
app 2 page 1
```

**When user clicks links in app1, these links DO affect browser's location, these links are processed by app1, and app2 is always reset to its `#/1` (so, whatever URL is, app2 should be at its own `#/1`).**

**When user clicks links in app2, this DOESN'T affect browser's location, these links are NOT processed by app1, and only app2 is affected. When user hits Refresh, app2 should be reset to its "zero state", which is `#/1`**

The only solution I can think of is to get rid of routing in app2 and just use `onclick`/`ng-click` for links instead. This seems to be a dirty hack.

Any chance I can still use routing in app2? If you got the idea, probably you know completely different solution which solves the problem - will also appreciate if you share it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you would want to use 2 apps in the same page?

Comment: ganaraj: no specific reason. If there's a chance to achieve the same by using single app with 2 controllers, that also will do. The only requirement is to have a set of `<a>` which doesn't affect browser URL.

Comment: The simplest solution for that is to have ng-click="onClick($event)" on the <a>'s and then in the onClick Handler do $event.preventDefault(); That should prevent the click from affecting the browser url.

Comment: This question may sound stupid but why don't you just combine the two apps? I also don't get why need certain routing in app2 if you don't want the app to interact with the location. Isn't that what the routing is made for? The only thing that would come is my mind to somehow adapt the example under HTML5mode which uses a fakebrowser: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

Comment: One of the reasons, like in my case, is if you want to create AngularJS based portlets. You can have multiple portlets on a single page. It is even possible to have multiple instances of one portlet on a single page. I've been fighting with this problem too. I've gotten simple apps to work, but once routing is needed, the app fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is often the need for multiple apps on the same page.

Does this help? 
--> http://jsfiddle.net/2yUAD/1/ <--

Basic idea (that's how I handle multi-apps with this glorious framework) is to 'sub-out' module apps.
I always have a 'Page' app and initialize sub apps whenever and wherever I need 'em.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi, your jsfillde does not solve the problem. There is still a coupling between the two applications