# Angular js model value changes are not reflected in ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Values in the UI doesn't change even after executing the code in controller. 
It displays the initial values with out a problem.
I've tried calling $scope.$apply() at the end of each function (submit and transfer) but it didn't work(it only gave an error with the $http.post()). What am i missing here?

```js
app.controller('RegisterController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http) {  
    $scope.user = {
        email: 'admin@blah.com',
        password1: '1qaz2wsx',
        password2:'1qaz2wsx',
        password:'1qaz2wsx',
        username:'Admin',
        profile_picture:'',
        dobDay:'12',
        dobMonth:'12',
        dobYear:'1993',
        date_of_birth:'',
        stateMessage:'',
        messageColor:'white',
    };
    
    var transfer = function(){
        $http.post('http://localhost/cw/index.php/rest/resource/user/action/create',$scope.user).then(function successCallback(response) {
            if(response.data.status!=null){
                if(response.data.status=='success'){
                    $scope.user.stateMessage = 'success';
                    $scope.user.messageColor = "green";
                }
                else if(response.data.status=='failure'){
                    $scope.user.stateMessage = response.data.message;
                    $scope.user.messageColor = "red";
                }
                
            }
        },function errorCallback(response) {
            $scope.user.stateMessage = "Error occured.";
            $scope.user.messageColor = "red";
        });
        
    };
    
    $scope.submit = function(){
        $scope.user.stateMessage="";
        $scope.user.messageColor="white";
        var proceed = true;
        
        if(!validateFields()){
            $scope.user.stateMessage = "All fields must be filled!";
            $scope.user.messageColor = "red";
            proceed = false;
        }
        
        if(validateDate($scope.user.dobDay,$scope.user.dobMonth,$scope.user.dobYear)){
            $scope.user.date_of_birth= $scope.user.dobYear+"-"+$scope.user.dobMonth+"-"+$scope.user.dobDay;
        }else {
            proceed = false;
            $scope.user.stateMessage = "Date is invalid!";
            $scope.user.messageColor = "red";
        }
            
        if($scope.user.password1!=$scope.user.password2){
            proceed = false;
            $scope.user.stateMessage = "Passwords don't match!";
            $scope.user.messageColor = "red";
            
        }else $scope.user.password = $scope.user.password1;
        if(proceed){
            var file = document.getElementById('filePicker').files[0];
            reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                $scope.user.profile_picture = JSON.stringify(e.target.result);
                $scope.$apply();
                console.log($scope.user.profile_picture);
                transfer();
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } 
        
        
        function validateFields(){
            /*some form validation*/
            return true;
        }
        
        function validateDate(day,month,year){
          /*some date validation*/
            return true;
        }
       
    }
}]);
```

HTML code

```html
 <div ng-controller="RegisterController">
        <span style="background-color:{{user.messageColor}}"><h4>{{user.stateMessage}}</h4></span>
    </div>
<table style="text-align: left" ng-controller="RegisterController">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Username
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" ng-bind="user.username" ng-model="user.username">
                                </td>       <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Email
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="email" ng-bind="user.email" ng-model="user.email">
                                </td>       <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Password
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="password" ng-bind="user.password1" ng-model="user.password1">
                                </td>       <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Retype password
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="password" ng-bind="user.password2" ng-model="user.password2">
                                </td>       <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>    
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Date of Birth
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" ng-bind="user.dobDay" ng-model="user.dobDay" value="DD" size="2" maxlength="2">
                                    <input type="text" ng-bind="user.dobMonth" ng-model="user.dobMonth" value="MM" size="2" maxlength="2">
                                    <input type="text" ng-bind="user.dobYear" ng-model="user.dobYear" value="YYYY" size="4" maxlength="4">
                                </td>    
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                                <td>
                                    Profile picture
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input id="filePicker" type="file" ng-bind="user.profile_picture" ng-model="user.profile_picture" accept="image/*">
                                    
                                </td>    
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                               <td></td>
                               <td style="float:left">
                                    <button ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's `http://localhost/cw/..` and not `http://localhost:xxxx/cw/..`. Port no. ?

Comment: The web service works fine. I can even see the values from chrome developer

Comment: Can you define and call 'transfer' function as a scope function and report the result?
i.e. $scope.transfer = function() {...} then 
$scope.transfer()

Comment: It used to be $scope.transfer = function(){...}

Comment: Can you post your HTML code as well?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like i cannot use the same controller in 2 instances.
Moving the status div in to the table assigned with the controller worked for me. There are ways to share data between controllers by using a service but i won't go there since this is only for a coursework.

[AngularJS: share the data of the same controller in two different, not nested parts of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299768/angularjs-share-the-data-of-the-same-controller-in-two-different-not-nested-pa)